# How to create bash file and allow it to accept an argument from the terminal?

Tags: bash

In recall for nostalgic feelings, I've remembered the .bat files on DOS. :)

Here's the thing:
Each time I need to generate a documentation for a given web application I have to:

sudo phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli -d public_html/yoursite.dev/application/ -t public_html/yoursite.dev/docs/

is there a way to make a shortcut to the above, so that, we can type only:

```
sudo generateDoc.sh -a yoursite.dev
```

or even better:

```
sudo generateDoc.sh -theVariableThatNeedsTobeChangedOnBashHere
```

So that, if we have yoursite.dev passed on the command line, the bash will have yoursite.dev, if we write yoursite2.dev then, the bash would have yoursite2.dev and so on...

Any clue?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli -d public_html/"$1"/application/ \
    -t public_html/"$1"/docs/
```

Call it as `sudo ./script.sh yoursite`.

Comment: I see that $1 means first argument. Why do we need the ./ ?

Comment: @MEM its so bash knows that the script your trying to run is in this directory for a little explanation look here http://www.linfo.org/dot_slash.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also place this function in your .bashrc:

```
generateDocs() {
    sudo phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli \
                -d "public_html/$1/application/" \
                -t "public_html/$1/docs/"
}
```

then

```
generateDocs yoursite.dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example script I wrote. The `$*` means "all the arguments passed". Importantly, they're in quotes because otherwise white space would break the command. Quodlibet is a sweet music library/player, btw.

```
jake@daedalus:~$ cat bin/play
#!/bin/bash
quodlibet --query "$*"
quodlibet --next
jake@daedalus:~$ play garrison keillor rhubarb pie
```

Like Fido said, don't forget to set the file as executable with `chmod +x programName`.

Something you might consider is making a `bin` directory in your home folder and adding it to your `$PATH`. Then you can call the command no matter what folder you're in. I have this line in my .bashrc: `PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH`. If you don't do this, you have use an absolute or relative path when you call your script, ie:

```
jake@daedalus:/usr/local/share/docs$ /home/jake/bin/play foo fighters everlong
jake@daedalus:~/bin$ ./play placebo where is my mind
```

I highly recommend [Grymoire's guide to SH scripting](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html). What you're needing to do is use the shell's [Positional Parameters](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-38) to take arguments and insert them into your command. There's also [TLDP's](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html) more in depth treatment of [BASH's Positional Parameters](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#POSPARAMREF). I'd start with Grymoire's, and then read through TLDP when you're ready for a more advanced treatment of the subject.

Comment: Actually, you should use `"$@"`, not `"$*"`. With `"$*"`, all arguments will be returned as a *single* string. With `"$@"`, all arguments will be returned as they were originally given.

Comment: @mssever Good distinction to make, but at least in my case, I do want the argument returned as a single string. [Grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-42) points out the difference.

Comment: @djeikyb: Since you know the difference between these two variables, I'm curious why you prefer `"$*"` in your case. The reason is that in all the shell scripting I've done, I've never encountered a situation where I've wanted `"$*"`. I always use `"$@"` so that I'm protected no matter what the arguments are. What's a situation where `"$*"` is better?

Comment: @mssever $* treats `play adele rumour has it` like one string: "adele rumour has it". $@ treats it as multiple arguments: "adele", "rumour", "has", "it". If I were to use $@, quodlibet will select all "adele" songs, then anything with "rumour" in the title, then anything with "has", etc.. when what I want is to select "adele rumour has it" all at once.

Comment: I would prefer to call `play "adele rumour has it"` and use "$@" in the script.

Comment: @enzotib Personal preference or compelling reason? I'm still a BASH newb, I've got no stake in my solution beyond "works for me".

Comment: @djeikyb: I would do the same as @enoztib, because that's the usual way things work in Bash. Typically, something that should be treated as a single string should be quoted; that way you can specify multiple arguments if you wish. Of course, for your own personal scripts you're free to do it however you want. But if you were distributing it, you should do it the standard way to avoid confusion. Personally, I prefer the flexibility of something like `play "adele rumour has it"`. Thanks for answering, though, and providing a use case for `$*`.

Answer (score 0):

Open your favorite text editor, paste the following:

```
args=("$@")
sudo phpdoc -o HTML:frames:earthli -d public_html/${args[0]}/application/ -t public_html/${args[0]}/docs/
```

and save it as (in this case) 'generateDoc.sh'. The next thing to do is to give execution rights to your file, so open a terminal, and run: `$ chmod +x generateDoc.sh`
Now all you need to do is call the file: `$ ./generateDoc.sh yoursite.dev` there's no need for `sudo` here, because it's already inside the sh file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Fido, I've thought about what I wanted to achieve and I've changed my question accordingly, if you happen to know, do you care to update your question as well?

Comment: Why, in order to run it, we need to do ./  ?

Comment: I've done chmod +x generateDodc.sh but I still need sudo :( Why?

Comment: You need the `./` beacuse that's the syntax to call a sh file, you can also run it with `sh` or `bash`.The fact that the file is executable doesn't mean that you don't need special privileges to run some things. (Although I'm not sure if special rights are needed to run phpdoc)

Comment: You need to quote your ${args[0]}